# Ubuntu 20.04 reboots repeatedly

Tags: 20.04, reboot

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on Azure. One day it started rebooting repeatedly. When I checked the OS startup screen, it started up normally until the middle of the process, but each service shut down from the middle of the process, Finally, the reboot occurs.
We would like to investigate the cause of the reboot. Please tell us what logs we should check to find the service that is causing the reboot.

[image]

Comment: `sudo journalctl -b -1 -ex` will show the end of previous boot's logs,  `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -x` will show beginning of current boot. `sudo journalctl  --list-boots` will list boots. Read `man journalctl  sudo`.